# SemanticsService.announce in flutter

Tags: flutter

Was going through code of a flutter library and found this being used

```
SemanticsService.announce(
            localizations.formatMonthYear(_selectedFirstDate), textDirection);
```

did a google search and read the flutter doc but still not sure what this does. Can anyone explain this to me or point to some resource which covers this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about accessibility.
You can have a look, what the method does:

```
     /// Sends a semantic announcement.
  ///
  /// This should be used for announcement that are not seamlessly announced by
  /// the system as a result of a UI state change.
  ///
  /// For example a camera application can use this method to make accessibility
  /// announcements regarding objects in the viewfinder.
  static Future<void> announce(String message, TextDirection textDirection) async {
    final AnnounceSemanticsEvent event = AnnounceSemanticsEvent(message, textDirection);
    await SystemChannels.accessibility.send(event.toMap());
  }
```

So basically a screen reader (VoiceOver / Talkback) will read out, what is passed in the message parameter.